# python quit function not working

Tags: python, exit

I am using the following check in one of my scripts:

```
if os.path.exists(FolderPath) == False:
    print FolderPath, 'Path does not exist, ending script.'
    quit()
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(FolderPath,GILTS)) == False:
    print os.path.join(FolderPath,GILTS), ' file does not exist, ending script.'
    quit()    
df_gilts = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(FolderPath,GILTS))
```

Stangely enough, when the path/file doesn't exist, I obtain the following print:

```
  IOError: File G:\On-shoring Project\mCPPI\Reconciliation Tool\Reconciliation Tool Project\3. Python\BootStrap\BBG\2017-07-16\RAW_gilts.csv does not exist
```

Tells me that it's continuing on with the script even though I've added a quit(). Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: You're checking `FolderPath` exists, but then accessing `FolderPath` with `FILTS` on the end - does the full path exist?

Comment: `quit()` is not a built in Python function. Have you defined it somewhere?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes it is

Comment: I'm assuming if the folder path exists, then the GILTS file will be present in that folder.

Comment: `quit()` is added by the site module.  It shouldn't be used for a script.  See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=quit#quit.  I'd use `sys.exit()`

Comment: That assumption appears to be wrong.

Comment: The assumption is fine. If the folder does exist, the file will be there (as there is another script which produces the folder and the files together). The quit() function catches when the folder is not present, which in my test case is true.

Comment: @thaavik when I use that the console returns "UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D." which is why I started using quit() instead.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but style tip: `if not os.path.exists(FolderPath):` is preferable over `if os.path.exists(FolderPath) == False:`. Comparing values directly to True or False is only the correct style in rare circumstances.

Comment: Since you do not get the output "Path does not exist, ending script", your script quite apparently does not enter the `if`, which means the folder exists, but the file within it apparently does not.

Comment: @naiminp what console do you refer to?  Your question referred to your code as a script.  If it's meant to be run as a script (i.e. not interactively by you in something other than the `python` interpreter), you should use `sys.exit`

Comment: What happens if you replace `quit()` with `raise IOError("Path does not exist")`?

Comment: I'ved edited the question and the same is still happening.

Comment: @Kevin I obtain the IOError as expected.

Comment: @thaavik I'm using sypder.

Comment: BTW, you might consider using PEP-8 compliant names so your code will be less confusing to other folks familiar with Python conventions -- the capitalization of the name `FolderPath` implies that it's a class, not a string, for example. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I didn't realise there was such a convention. Will apply to my code going forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=quit#constants-added-by-the-site-module), `quit()` (like other functions added by the `site` module) is intended only for interactive use.

Thus, the solution is twofold:

- Check whether `os.path.exists(os.path.join(FolderPath, GILTS))`, not just `os.path.exists(FolderPath)`, to ensure that the code attempting to exit the interpreter is actually reached.
- Use `sys.exit(1)` (after `import sys` in your module header, of course) to halt the interpreter with an exit status indicating an error from a script.

That said, you might consider just using exception handling:

```
from __future__ import print_function

path = os.path.join(FolderPath, GILTS)
try:
    df_gilts = pd.read_csv(path)
except IOError:
    print('I/O error reading CSV at %s' % (path,), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still seeing the entire log: 
"UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1"

returned in my spyder console. I was looking for a way for it to just end with the print message intended but will accept this answer and move on.

Comment: Ahh! That's specifically a Spyder (or, more generally, an IDE) thing. Users directly running the code at an interactive interpreter won't see a SystemExit exception.